# ora 12541: no listener oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

I have installed Oracle 12c server and client on the same laptop.

Previously it was running, but now I started getting this error `ORA-12541: no listener`.

My listener service is up and running, and I can connect through SQL Developer, but I get that error when I try to connect through SQL*Plus using `system/Lab12345@lab`.

```
C:\Users\hunai>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 15-JUN-2017 12:57:07
Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))

STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
>Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                15-JUN-2017 12:38:45
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 18 min. 23 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\hunai\product\12.1.0\dbhome\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\hunai\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-0RL2PU2\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-0RL2PU2)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\APP\HUNAI\admin\lab\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "lab" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "lab", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "labXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "lab", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

This is my `tnsnames.ora` file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\hunai\product\12.1.0\dbhome\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LAB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = lab)
    )
  )

LISTENER_LAB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Kindly tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What are you doing when you get that error? Have you rebooted and picked up a different IP address via DHCP perhaps, and your listener is now on that address but you're trying to connect to the old one - maybe? You could include your `tnsnames.ora` in your question if you're trying to connect via a TNS alias.

Comment: no i have edited sqldeveloper.config file to give new java path and to run it now sql developer is up and running and connected but sql plus login is not working

Comment: How are you connecting from SQL Developer, and how are you trying to connect from SQL\*Plus?

Comment: I am connecting on local machine server and client both are on same laptop.

Comment: And I am connecting through sql plus using system/Lab12345@lab

Comment: OK, so how is the `lab` alias defined in your `tnsnames.ora`? I suggested adding that to the question. Seems like that definition will have the wrong IP address (or host name) or port.

Comment: Done. Now please give me solution ?

Comment: That looks OK, unless `localhost` has been changed in your `etc\hosts` file, and I think that woudl be giving you other problems. To rule that out can you changed your `tnsnames.ora` to refer explicitly to 127.0.0.1 instead of `localhost`?

Comment: can you do team viewer and check what is an Issue and fix please ?

Comment: Are you there please tell me ?

Comment: You know that people here are volunteers, not your personal support service? Please don't be so demanding. And no, I won't do team viewer, whatever that is. Have you tried changing the `tnanames.ora` as I suggested, or checked your hosts file? Are you sure you're looking at the right file? (server and client could have separate ones). What has changed in your system or config since it was working?

Comment: I have changed localhost to My computer name and I have changed files from server And after that I get error :

Enter user-name: system/Lab12345@lab
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Comment: It worked like a charm brother thank you so much 
I have put this ip 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as you advised and now it is working

Comment: @AlexPoole I need your help I have did what you said and it starts working but now again today I am facing the same error 

ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Please Help

Comment: I'm not sure what you ended up doing. If you switched everything to 127.0.0.1 then what else has changed since? If you changed it to your machine name maybe you just got a new IP address from DHCP. Can't tell from here, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if listener works:

```
lsnrctl status
```

in command line.

If it not works, try to start it:

```
lsnrctl start
```

Comment: C:\Users\hunai>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 15-JUN-2017 13:00:32

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started

Comment: But still i am not able to login in sql plus it gives me same error

Comment: try `lsnrctl stop` and then `lsnrctl start`

Comment: Both Commands completed successfully but still gets same error

Comment: Can you suggest anything else ?